# Learning to Reverse a Linked List

Tags: java

I have the below code to reverse a Linked List:

```
public class ProgrammingInterviews {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new List();
        list.add(new Node(1));
        list.add(new Node(2));
        list.add(new Node(3));
        list.add(new Node(4));
        list.reverse();
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}

class List {
    Node head;
    public List() {
        head = new Node(0);
    }

    public void add(Node node) {
        if (head.next == null) {
            head.next = node;
        } else {
            Node temp = head.next;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = node;
        }
    }

    public void reverse() {
        this.head = reverse(this.head);
    }

    private Node reverse(Node n) {
        if (n == null || n.next == null) {
            return n;
        }
        Node remaining = reverse(n.next);
        n.next.next = n;
        n.next = null;
        return remaining;

    }

    public String toString() {
        Node temp = head;
        String result = "HEAD";
        while (temp.next != null) {
            result = result + "->" + temp.next.data;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get it print `HEAD->4->3->2->1` with no avail. But, it is printing `HEAD->3->2->1`. Is there anything I'm missing.

Also, if you have tips of how to solve these types of problems it would really help me. I've been doing programming for some time. It is very good for problem solving. I come up with naive solutions easily. But, in the territory of data structures and Algorithms where we have think through different ideas/ways to come up with a solution I'm always found short.

For example, in this problem, I would have never thought that using recursion there is a solution. I'm using a solution looked up somewhere else. It would really help if I get some tips that would get me on the right track to solve these types of problems.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger for step-by-step code execution.

Comment: The way this was written reminds me of an awesome site where I enjoy practicing my code. [HackerRank - Reverse a Linked List](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reverse-a-linked-list). Since your title states that you're learning, I feel that this is a great place to expand your skill set. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how you conceptualize your linked list's head. When you construct your list, you assign:

```
public List() {
    head = new Node(0);
}
```

The list is theoretically empty, but we already have an element! Your data structure does not really represent the data accurately, although in most cases you ignore this by taking a look at head.next. For instance:

```
public String toString() {
    Node temp = head;
    String result = "HEAD";
    while (temp.next != null) {
        result = result + "->" + temp.next.data;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You're walking the list by looking at temp.next. Since we start at head, we never look at its value, and the first value we print is head.next (if it's not null).

Now, take a look at the reverse method:

```
public void reverse() {
    this.head = reverse(this.head);
}
```

Does this sound weird? We had fake value at head and we were deliberately ignoring it, but now we've overwritten it. And what have we overwritten it with?

Well, if `reverse()` is working properly, the new head will be the old last element. In your case, that would be...the 4 element! But we're ignoring the head in `toString()`, so the 4 will never be printed.

I run the code you provided, and it actually prints `HEAD->3->2->1->0`, which shouldn't be a surprise since the list was reversed, and that ghost 0 element has now been pushed to the end.

My advice here is try to keep the structure simple: when the list is empty, the head should probably be null. And instead of `while(temp.next != null)`, maybe you can do `while(temp != null)`, since we no longer have a base node (if the head is null, head.next is illegal), and `temp.next` on the last element's next should always be null (this does not apply to `add()`, since we need that reference to the last element).

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation makes sense. I overlooked the fact the last node's value is value of the head in the reversed list.